# How do I use ember-crumbly for non-nested routes?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, ember.js, breadcrumbs

I'm trying add breadcrumbs to this [application](https://training.teamgaslight.com/classroom/#/courses/14/chapters/152) using [ember-crumbly](https://github.com/poteto/ember-crumbly).

*I couldn't find the git repo, so to see the code, you'll have to clone the full application by clicking the button "Download git repository" in Course Material and then go to the branch step-14 by running the following command after going into the repo via command line:*

```
git checkout step-14
```

I'm adding breadcrumbs by making the following changes to the files:

**app/routes/album.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  breadCrumb: {
    title: 'Album'
  }
});
```

**app/routes/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  breadCrumb: {
    title: 'Home'
  },
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('album');
  }
});
```

**app/templates/application.hbs**

```
<header>
  <h1>BümBöx</h1>
</header>

<div class="breadcrumb">
  {{bread-crumbs tagName="ul" outputStyle="foundation"}}
</div>

{{outlet}}

{{now-playing}}
```

I'm hoping when I go to `http://localhost:4200/album/1`, it would look like this:
[image]

but instead, it looks like this:
[image]

I'm guessing it's because my routes are not nested in directories (as in it's not app/routes/home/album.js), which isn't compatible with the demo from ember-crumbly. Can someone help me figure out how to add ember-crumbly to this application? Much appreciate.

Comment: You guess right. Route `album` isn't nested in `index`

Comment: How do I add breadcrumbs without nesting my routes?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible